# How to define required attributes in JSON-LD contexts

Tags: json-ld

I'm building a system that relies heavily on JSON-LD. I have a graph database where I create vertices, and the vertices all must have a context. The context in turn defines all the necessary attributes that the vertex can have.
The problem with only using the context, is that the front-end application does not know which of the attributes are required and which are not.

I've been looking into Markus Lanthaler's Hydra console and the event demo API, and there I found out that it is using a `vocab` which defines all the supported classes and supported properties.
In the properties, a `required: true|false` attribute is defined, which is exactly what I need.
Now the question is, is this the only way to define required attributes in JSON-LD?

The context:

```
{
  "@context": {
    "@version": 1.1,
    "@vocab": "https://example.com/vocabularies/building.jsonld#",
    "pref": {
      "@id": "https://example.com/ontologies/core.jsonld#",
      "@prefix": true
    },
    "name": "pref:name",
    "data": "pref:data",
    "permanentBuildingNumber": {
      "@id": "pref:permanentBuildingNumber",
      "@nest": "data"
    }
  }
}
```

The vocabulary:

```
{
  "@context": {
    "@version": 1.1,
    "pref": {
      "@id": "https://example.com/ontologies/core.jsonld#",
      "@prefix": true
    },
    "@vocab": "https://example.com/vocabularies/building.jsonld#"
  },
  "@id": "https://example.com/vocabularies/building.jsonld",
  "@type": "pref:Vocabulary",
  "pref:supportedClass": [
    {
      "@id": "pref:Building",
      "@type": "pref:Building",
      "pref:supportedProperty": [
        {
          "pref:property": "pref:name",
          "pref:title": "name",
          "pref:description": "The name of the vertex.",
          "pref:required": true
        },
        {
          "pref:property": "pref:permanentBuildingNumber",
          "pref:title": "Permanent building number",
          "pref:description": "A unique identifier for the building.",
          "pref:required": true
        },
        {
          "pref:property": "pref:data",
          "pref:title": "data",
          "pref:description": "Contains the attributes of the vertex.",
          "pref:required": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

From this, the front-end can get the necessary information and dynamically create input fields for each attribute, but also know that the `Building` is the only value for the `@type`-field.

I haven't found any other way to go about this problem, and most JSON-LD usage examples are just simple product page or similar.

Is the vocabulary the only solution to my problem, or are there any other ways? 
This approach makes it pretty hard to maintain, as all types of vertices need their own context AND vocabulary to define the required attributes.